# Primefaces command button don't update after redirect

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

well this is my problem.

**What i need:** when i use the p:commandButton, do something in database, redirect to same page, hide the button and the status message will appear.

**What's going on:** when i use the p:commandButton, did something in database, redirect to same page, but neither was update. The p:commandButton is yet displayed and the status message was not. Like if the redirect wasn't work.

One strange thing is, if i click in the link (top of page) both are updated, behaving correctly.

**My url:** *localhost/myapp/mypage.xhtml*

**My model class:**

```
public class MyClass {

    private String name;
    private boolean waitingDeleteConfirmation;

    // getters/setters
}
```

**My Managed Bean:**

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyClassManagedBean {

    private List<MyClass> list;

    @PostConstruct
    public void load() {
        this.list = //database get list;
    }

    public boolean showButton(MyClass myClass){
        if(myClass.isWaitingDeleteConfirmation() && isPossibleDelete()/*came from database as TRUE*/)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String doDelete(MyClass) {
        //do something in database
        return "mypage?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

**My xhtml page:**

```
<h:link outcome="mypage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" value="Delete Page"/>

<h:form>
<p:dataTable value="#{myClassManagedBean.list}" var="listItem">

<p:column headerText="Name">
    <h:outputText value="#{listItem.name}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Delete">
    <p:commandButton rendered="#{myClassManagedBean.showButton(listItem)}"
                     action="#{myClassManagedBean.doDelete(listItem)}"
                     ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-trash" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Status">
    <h:outputText rendered="#{not myClassManagedBean.showButton(listItem)}" value="Waiting confirmation" />
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `showButton` should take in an instance of `NewClass` and not `MyClass` as parameter, that's one mistake already. Also your redirect method is not right, the page extension is missing.

Comment: Excuse me, corrected the class name.

Comment: ulima, `if(myClass.isWaitingDeleteConfirmation() && isPossibleDelete()/*came from database as TRUE*/)` then the method `showButton` returned false.. Is it what you want ? Maybe just switch `false` and `true`.